# Physical Sector Size on Windows XP for advanced format hard disks

Tags: c++, windows-xp, hard-drive, sector

I need to retrieve the physical sector size of a hard disk to determine if the hard disk is of advanced format or not in Windows XP.

I tried to use [`STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800831(v=vs.85).aspx), but it is not compatible in Windows XP. Any method I use would return 512 instead of 4096, which includes WMI where the only value returned is 512.

I have been coding in C++ and I would be very thankful if one can point me to a method which would help me find the actual physical sector size.

Comment: STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR is only valid from VISTA, an in windows xp, the windows api and WMI returns only 512 even for a 4096 sector size hard disk

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/advanced-format-disk-compatibility-update):

> Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, and Windows Server 2003 R2 do not
>   support 512e or 4Kn media. While the system may boot up and be able to
>   operate minimally, there may be unknown scenarios of functionality
>   issues, data loss, or sub-optimal performance. Thus, Microsoft
>   strongly cautions against using 512e media with Windows XP or other
>   products based on the Windows XP codebase (such as Windows Home Server
>   1.0, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows XP 64-bit Edition, Windows XP Embedded, Windows Small Business Server 2003, and
>   Windows Small Business Server 2003 R2).

Under Windows XP, you will not be able to get a true physical sector size because the OS itself assumes that it is 512 bytes.